# Java - BufferedWriter overwriting lines issue

Tags: java, newline, overwrite, bufferedwriter

So I have a JFrame with a button that accesses this method to write a String to a text file:

```
 public static void writeTest(String item) {
    File file = new File (directory + "TestFile.txt");
        try {
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
            out.write(item);
            out.newLine();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
   }
```

This part works fine, but if I click the button again, it will always write over the first line, even though I have the newLine(); there. I even tried putting newLine(); before AND after out.write(); , but it just replaces the first line of the file with a blank space, and then writes the 'item' String on the second line. I want it to write a line of String, save it in the text file, and when I write a new line, it ADDS a line of text to the file, not overwrite it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [BufferedWriter to write to file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11543338/bufferedwriter-to-write-to-file)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java FileWriter with append mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225146/java-filewriter-with-append-mode)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write file in append mode:

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
```

Here, `new FileWriter(file, true)`, true is flag for append mode

Comment: Thanks! This worked and I understand now for future reference.

Comment: @David, kindly accept the answer as it worked for you

Comment: Haha sorry I couldn't figure out how to choose an answer for the life of me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Open FileWriter in append mode

Comment: how it is done: `BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));`